# ArcGIS Pro calculate field using arcade not working?

Tags: field-calculator, arcgis-pro, expression, arcade

Im trying to calculate a field called "bark t/ha" using the following expression:

```
if ($feature.Barkfuelhaz =="Low"){
  return"0"}
else if($feature.Barkfuelhaz =="Moderate"){
  return"1"}
else if($feature.Barkfuelhaz == "High"){
  return"2"}
else if($feature.Barkfuelhaz == "Very High"){
  return"5"}
else if($feature.Barkfuelhaz == "Extreme"){
  return"7"}
```

the expression validates however when I run it, all values in the Bark/ta field change to "0"

I've even tried running a simpler one "if ($feature.Barkfuelhaz == "Moderate"){
  Return "2"}"
but all values still stay as 0

Comment: What is the data type of the field you are calculating? Maybe `return "0"` should be `return 0`?

Comment: What version of ArcGIS Pro are you using?

Answer (score 1):

To test this I used Create Fishnet to create a 3x3 grid to which I added a Text field called Barkfuelhaz and populated it as below:

[image]

I then added a Short Integer field that I named IntField and tried to calculate it using your expression:

[image]

and it worked:

[image]

I was a little surprised that returning strings to an integer field did not cause problems.

Consequently, I am unable to reproduce your problem.  My testing was performed using a beta version of ArcGIS Pro but I would expect that ArcGIS Pro 2.4.2 would behave the same with respect to this test.